# What is missing to install transform with pip in Databricks Cluster runtime version 7.3?

Tags: python, pip, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to revitalize an old project. To do that i need to create a Cluster Runtime version 7.3, then install the python library ***transform***.
Transform: https://pypi.org/project/transform/1.0.20/#history

I have tried the latest, 1.0.21, 1.0.20, 1.0.19, and 1.0.18. I get the following error:
[image]

1. What does this message actuallt mean?

   - Metric lite: https://pypi.org/project/metricflow-lite/#history
2. How can i install transform in databricks cluster with runtime version 7.3?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to install the **transform==1.0.19** and **transform==1.0.18** Library on databricks runtime **7.3**

I have encountered the same error as you while installing PyPI package on cluster UI.

[image]

[image]

**Error Message:**

***Library installation attempted on the driver node of cluster 0829-081356-d3dhmwqd and failed. Please refer to the following error message to fix the library or contact Databricks support. Error Code: DRIVER_LIBRARY_INSTALLATION_FAILURE. Error Message: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Process List(/databricks/python/bin/pip, install, transform==1.0.19, --disable-pip-version-check) exited with code 1. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement metricflow-lite>=0.130.1 (from transform_tools<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->transform==1.0.19) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for metricflow-lite>=0.130.1 (from transform_tools<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->transform==1.0.19)***

- The error message related metricflow & transform indicates that there was an issue while trying to install a library called "transform" on the driver node of a Databricks cluster

I have tried another approach with same runtime **7.3** and changed the cluster policy to **Personal Compute.**

I have also tried using the **Unrestricted** Policy too. Below are the steps

**Personal Compute:**
[image]

**Unrestricted Compute:**
[image]

**Step 1:** Upgrade the Version

```
%pip install --upgrade pip
```

[image]

**Step 2:** Install Transform 1.0.18

```
%pip install transform==1.0.18
```

[image]

**Step 3:** Check the transform version

```
import transform
print(transform.__version__)
```

[image]

Comment: So, you did not solve it? You still have a problem?

Comment: I am able to download this by using step 1-3 i have used %pip install transform==1.0.18
try it and let me know if it helped.